# Only give the element which i click on a style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am making a filter for my page.
Everything works but the only problem i cant get solved is how to give a style to the button i press on. When i try it with jQuery it gives all the buttons the style.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="filter_options">
    <!-- <div class="map_trigger"></div>
    <div class="list_trigger active"></div>-->
<h3 style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 15px!important;">Kies een discipline: </h3>
    <div id="uwpqsf_id">
    <form id="uwpqsffrom_43">
        <div class="uform_title">Projecten</div>
           <input type="hidden" name="unonce" value="8fa32e7b04">
           <input type="hidden" name="uformid" value="43">
           <input type="hidden" id="uajaxdiv" value=".projecten_list">
           <div class="uwpqsf_class " id="tax-radio-0">
              <span class="taxolabel-0">Disciplines</span>
              <input type="hidden" name="taxo[0][name]" value="Werkgebied">
              <input type="hidden" name="taxo[0][opt]" value="">
              <label>
              <input type="radio" id="tradio-0-0" class="tradio-0" name="taxo[0][term]" value="uwpqsftaxoall">Disciplines</label>
              <label>
              <input type="radio" id="tradio-0-1" class="tradio-0" name="taxo[0][term]" value="bagger">Bagger</label>
              <label><input type="radio" id="tradio-0-2" class="tradio-0" name="taxo[0][term]" value="groen">Groen</label>
              <label><input type="radio" id="tradio-0-3" class="tradio-0" name="taxo[0][term]" value="infra">Infra</label>
              <label><input type="radio" id="tradio-0-4" class="tradio-0" name="taxo[0][term]" value="milieutec">Milieutec</label></div>    

                    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var formid = "#uwpqsffrom_43";
    $(formid).find('input, textarea, button, select').change(function(){ 
        process_data($(this)); 

        })
      ;})</script>
  <div style="clear:both"></div></form></div>       </div>
```

I need to get a style on the label which i click on, i have tried with onclick label function but it is giving all the labels the css.

Here is the code i have tried:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("label").click(function(){
       $("label").css("background-color: black;");
    });
});
```

I also can't add any new ID or classes to the HTML because its being generated by a plugin ..

Comment: did you try $(this) ??

Comment: Simple, replace `$("label").css("background-color: black;");` with `$(this).css("background-color: black;");` you should already know since you're using `$(this)` in other parts of your script....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are pushing the label by plugin you need to change you code like this way

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'label', function(){
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
   });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'label', function(){
  if( $('label').hasClass('red')){
    $(this).each(function(index, element) {
              $('label').removeClass('red');
           });
  }
       $(this).addClass('red')
    });
});
```

```css
.red {
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<label> click me </label>
<label> click me </label>
<label> click me </label>
<label> click me </label>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Naila , but when i click on a other label the background-color of other labels need to be removed. Can you help me with this?

Comment: yep , wait a minute

Comment: Please tick the answer if its use full to you

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("label").click(function(){
        $("label").css("background-color: black;");
    });
});
```

change to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("label").click(function(){
       $(this).css("background-color: black;");
    });
});
```

as @deep said.

Comment: Actually the frist this is wrong, this in that context is document.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` inside an event handler to reference just the single element which fired the event.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("label").click(function(){
       $(this).css("background-color: black;");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter passed in to the .css function is incorrect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("label").click(function(){
       $(this).css("background-color", "black");
    });
});
```